# Equation not generated for graph in excel 2016 but works for excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a macro that plots a graph and writes the equation at the side (refer to picture below), the codes are as follows -

```
Sub PopulateData(CurrentChart As Chart, SiteNames As Range)

Dim DataCount As Integer
Dim Dataindex As Integer
Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim DataColLet As String
Dim LastLegend As Integer
Dim SeriesCount As Integer

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
DataCount = SiteNames.Count
SeriesCount = 1

With CurrentChart

    'Going through each Data Set
    For i = 2 To DataCount

        If SiteNames(i).Font.Strikethrough = False Then
            'Gets the data column letter
            DataColLet = ToColletter(ActiveSheet.Rows(2).Find(What:=SiteNames(i), LookIn:=xlValues).Column)

            'Create a series to load the data
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .ChartArea.Font.Size = 14

            On Error Resume Next

            With .SeriesCollection(SeriesCount)

                'Load the data
                .XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$3:$A$" & LastRow
                .Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$" & DataColLet & "$3:$" & DataColLet & "$" & LastRow

                'Add the trend line
                .Trendlines.Add
                .Trendlines(1).Type = xlPower
                .Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True
                'Formats the points and trendline
                .Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Font.ColorIndex = i + 7
                .Trendlines(1).Border.ColorIndex = i + 7
                .MarkerStyle = 8
                .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = i + 7
                .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = i + 7
                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") / 1000)
                ActiveSheet.Cells(SiteNames(i).Row, 1) = ActiveSheet.Cells(SiteNames(i).Row, 1) & " " & .Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text
                .Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Delete
                .Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!$A$" & SiteNames(i).Row

            End With

            LastLegend = .Legend.LegendEntries.Count
            .Legend.LegendEntries(LastLegend).Delete
            SeriesCount = SeriesCount + 1

        End If

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Below is the graph with equation generated after running the macro.

Graph with equation
[image]

However, when running the same code in excel 2016, the equation will not be generated in my file. Below is the graph without the equation generated.

Graph without equation
[image]

Hence may I know what code needs to tweaked such that the equation can be generated on the excel 2016? The following code `.Trendlines(1).DisplayEquation = True` has already been keyed in so may I know what's the problem for the equation to be not generated? Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you ask, but your LastRow is weird.

Comment: ! $ A $ 3: $ A $ "& LastRow This part makes a chart and there is a mismatch.

Comment: I'm not too sure what the LastRow does too but when I printed it out, it gives me the last row of column 1, just right before the first blank cell (using the first picture as an example, it will not print out 22 as there are blank spaces before row 20. Instead, it prints 17 (cant be seen in the picture) as there is a blank space at A18.)

Comment: But even if there is a mismatch, why would I be able to generate an equation at excel 2010 but not in excel 2016? Thanks for helping. @Dy.Lee

Comment: Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") / 1000) ,  Advise you to increase your time.

Comment: I have tried to increase it to Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:50:00") / 1000), but I have gotten the same result. Only difference is that it takes longer to generate the graph. @Dy.Lee

Comment: I have found out why the equation cant be printed out. '.Trendlines(1).DataLabel.Text' seems to not work in 2016 excel for some reason, when i tried to debug.print it nothing came out but it can be printed out for 2010 excel. How do I go around changing it? There isn't any change in syntax so I don't know why it isnt printing it out